# Dask groupby over each column separately gives out wrong result

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-distributed

I am simulating here with dummy data what I actually want to do. The steps I need to perform:

1. Do some transformation over each column separately.
2. Do groupby operation for aggregate some metrics for each column against a target column.

The code which I have simulated.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.distributed import Client, as_completed, LocalCluster

cluster = LocalCluster(processes=False)

client = Client(cluster, asynchronous=True)

csv_loc = '/Users/apple/Downloads/iris.data'
df = dd.read_csv(csv_loc) # ofcourse, u need to give aws creds here. Omitting it. Assuming u can read from s3 or otherwise.
client.persist(df)
cols = ['sepal_length', 'sepal_width' ,'petal_length' ,'petal_width', 'species']

# This is needed because I am doing some custom operation on actual data
for c in cols:
    if c != 'species':
        df[c] = df[c].map(lambda x: x*10)
client.persist(df) # Is this the trouble?

def agg_bivars(col_name):
    agg_df = df.groupby('species')[col_name].sum().compute()
    return {col_name : agg_df}

agg_futures = client.map(agg_bivars, ['sepal_length', 'sepal_width' ,'petal_length' ,'petal_width'])

for batch in as_completed(agg_futures, with_results=True).batches():
   for future, result in batch:
       print('result: {}'.format(result))


client.restart()
client.close()
cluster.close()
```

You can download the data from this [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uiuc-cse/data-fa14/gh-pages/data/iris.csv). This is a very standard popular data available online.

**The result I get**: Same result groupby result for different columns.

**Expected result**: Need different groupby result for different columns.

Result:

```
result: {'sepal_width': species
Iris-setosa        2503.0
Iris-versicolor    2968.0
Iris-virginica     3294.0
Name: sepal_length, dtype: float64}
result: {'sepal_length': species
Iris-setosa        2503.0
Iris-versicolor    2968.0
Iris-virginica     3294.0
Name: sepal_length, dtype: float64}
result: {'petal_width': species
Iris-setosa        2503.0
Iris-versicolor    2968.0
Iris-virginica     3294.0
Name: sepal_length, dtype: float64}
result: {'petal_length': species
Iris-setosa        2503.0
Iris-versicolor    2968.0
Iris-virginica     3294.0
Name: sepal_length, dtype: float64}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

If I do only groupby on df, it works fine. But, the issue here is I **have** to do some transformation on entire df before groupby on each column separately. Note I am doing `client.persist(df)` twice. I did second time because whatever new transformations I have done, I want them to persist so that I can query quickly.

Comment: The second `client.persist` is unnecessary and the first should be called as `df =  client.persist(df)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `compute()` within the `agg_bivars` function.

Try the following code:

```
def agg_bivars(col_name):
    agg_df = df.groupby('species')[col_name].sum()  #.compute()
    return {col_name : agg_df}

agg_futures = client.map(agg_bivars, ['sepal_length', 'sepal_width' ,'petal_length' ,'petal_width'])

for batch in as_completed(futures=agg_futures, with_results=True).batches():    
    for future, result in batch:        
        print(f'result: {list(result.values())[0].compute()}')
```

results with :

```
result: species
setosa        2503.0
versicolor    2968.0
virginica     3294.0
Name: sepal_length, dtype: float64
result: species
setosa        1709.0
versicolor    1385.0
virginica     1487.0
Name: sepal_width, dtype: float64
result: species
setosa         732.0
versicolor    2130.0
virginica     2776.0
Name: petal_length, dtype: float64
result: species
setosa         122.0
versicolor     663.0
virginica     1013.0
Name: petal_width, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Wouldn't the last line `print(f'result: {list(result.values())[0].compute()}')` block until compute? The entire operation becomes sequential because until the first `compute()` is finished, one cannot go to the second.

Comment: If you add `time.sleep(5)` to `agg_bivars` you will realize that it's not sequential.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you are overcomplicating  things.

## Pandas

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("iris.csv")

df[df.columns[:-1]] = df[df.columns[:-1]] * 10

df.groupby("species").sum()

            sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width
species                                                         
setosa            2503.0       1709.0         732.0        122.0
versicolor        2968.0       1385.0        2130.0        663.0
virginica         3294.0       1487.0        2776.0       1013.0
```

## Dask

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.read_csv("iris.csv")
for col in df.columns[:-1]:
    df[col] = df[col]*10

df.groupby("species").sum().compute()

            sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width
species                                                         
setosa            2503.0       1709.0         732.0        122.0
versicolor        2968.0       1385.0        2130.0        663.0
virginica         3294.0       1487.0        2776.0       1013.0
```

Then if you want the result as `dict` you just need to add `to_dict()` to the output.

Comment: My point is not doing Groupby-sum, but doing operation on each column. In this example, it is on just `species` column. I might have more than one column to groupby but separately. I want correction in my actual code.